# What is the equivalent coordinates of returned extent and coordinate of ol4 dragbox

Tags: openlayers, coordinates

When I tried to console the result of dragbox coordinates it returns an 2d array.   What is the meaning of coordinates returned?

I need to get the points to use it in SQL and make a polygon.

Index 0 is minx and miny and what about the others?

```
dragBox.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
0:[13466767.761325281, 1601017.3688731098]
1:[13466767.761325281, 1601011.3225847394]
2:[13466776.737450918, 1601011.3225847394]
3:[13466776.737450918, 1601017.3688731098]
4:[13466767.761325281, 1601017.3688731098]
```

Comment: maxx and maxy. There are only 2 x and 2 y, and the corners are the 4 possible combos of those.

Answer (score 1):

Those ones is the corner coordinates of the box you're plotting.(The box is meaning DrawBox) Index 0 and 4 same values, because it must be a polygon. You can use these values to plotting a polygon.